# "Kristina 'has passed'/'passed' her exam! She 'has got'/'got' 90%"

Tags: phrase-usage, past-tense, present-perfect

> 1. Kristina has passed her exam!
> 2. Kristina passed her exam!

Does English use the present perfect (1) or the past tense (2) to announce news?

Apart the way to express the vote—90%, 90, I don't know—which of the following sentences is more natural to give further details?

> a. She has got 90%.
>
> b. She got 90%.

Answer (score 4):

1 and 2 are both correct, and at least from US usage probably occurs relatively equally. However, the impression is not quite the same.

> 1. Kristina has passed her exam!

This implies that it was unexpected, or that she had some difficulty passing her exam.

> 1. Kristina passed her exam!

This is just a simple statement of fact (other than the !).

> a. She has got 90%.

You can't use "got" with a helper verb. Should be "has gotten".
But I think "has gotten" is a poor word to use in this context. Something like

> Her score was 90%.

is probably better.

Comment: I agree with you, but note that "has got" versus "has gotten" is a complicated subject, and many people do not use "gotten" under any circumstances.  See http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gotten.html for details.

Comment: Agreed. My comment "But I think "got" is a poor word to use in this context." should have said "has gotten". I'll edit my reply.

Comment: The sentence "You can't use "got" with a helper verb. Should be "has gotten"." is not true in all regions. To me (a native of south-east England), "gotten" is not part of my vocabulary at all. I agree that using the verb "to get" in this context is not the best choice, but if I had to use it, "she has got" would be perfectly valid.